# How to get SINR and RSSI values pragmatically? I have seen a lot of posts, all theory or discussion, none was worked

Tags: android, telephony, lte

How to get SINR and RSSI values pragmatically for LTE. I am looking or an Android Kotlin or Java example. I have seen a lot of posts, all theory or discussions, none has helped me.
I also need PUSCH TX Power, PUCCH TX Power and any other metrics that are available that relate to the strength and quality of the signal.
 Please Help.
Thank you

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: I had to put away that project and started working on a different project. I could still use help, but most important is TX Power.